# FastAPI WebSocket 'opening handshake failed' with UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters

Tags: websocket, fastapi

I am implementing websockets in FastAPI. The websockets library version is 12.0, and the FastAPI version is 0.89.1.

```
@router.websocket("/ws/{room_id}")
async def websocket_endpoint(ws: WebSocket, room_id: str, token: str):
    """
    Handles WebSocket communication for a specific room.
    """
    # code
```

I am encountering the following error: **UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 5-6: ordinal not in range(128)**. No part of the code is getting executed. It says '**opening handshake failed**'.

Following is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/websockets/legacy/server.py", line 167, in handler
    await self.handshake(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/websockets/legacy/server.py", line 587, in handshake
    early_response = await early_response_awaitable
```

What could be the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: How are you making the request? What is the stack trace for the error?

Comment: @MatsLindh
Following is the traceback:

`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/websockets/legacy/server.py", line 167, in handler
    await self.handshake(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/websockets/legacy/server.py", line 587, in handshake
    early_response = await early_response_awaitable
`